# Intellij: Getting Started with Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, intellij-idea, google-cloud-tools

I try to create a Google App Engine project in Intellij 2016.3 based on [this tutorial](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/getting-started-with-google-app-engine.html?utm_content=2016.3). The described "Google App Engine" plugin does not exist. I used the "Google Cloud Tools" instead. I enabled it, downloaded the actual Cloud SDK and added it to the App Engine under "Build, Execution, Deployment".

When I try to create an App Engine project as described in the tutorial, I should add under "Additional Libraries and Frameworks" the Google App Engine but this selection is not available. The project created without it is a standard Java project with no relation to the App Engine.

What do I have to do to create a Google App Engine project in Intellij?

Comment: Do you have the Ultimate or Community edition? GAE support is only available in the Ultimate edition: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the answer is already in the comment from Dan Comilescu above. I found it independently after exchanging almost 10 emails with Jetbrains. They first told me that Google App Engine is included by default into Intellij. Therefore everything should just work as described. Only after checking the logs they became aware that the problem is that it is only included in the Ultimate edition of Intellij. The Community edition does not have it and therefore can not use it! I urged them to put that on top of their tutorial page and meanwhile they have added it.